# Stuck at boot, no GUI, login on tty not possible after upgrade to Debian 12

Tags: debian, login, gui, dist-upgrade, boot-process

I upgraded my system to `Debian 12`, but I cannot login any more after I rebooted when the package installation seemed to be completed. The login prompt (on tty) tells me `login incorrect` after typing any (even empty, even `root`) string with my keyboard and finishing it with `Return` (standard way to type in a user name).
Sometimes the issue in comparable situations is because there's no space left on the device. I'm pretty sure I can exclude this as a possible reason here because I cheked that every partition has at least several MB of free space with `gnome-disks` from a live system.

The screen at `Ctrl+Alt+F7` is stuck at `[  OK  ] Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.` with a blinking underscore cursor in the line under the fullstop. The line breaks don't work correctly as it seems to add the space of a whole line to do the line break, not just breaking the line and starting at position 0 for writing the next line.

I'd like to not reinstall my system in order to use it again.

`Ctrl+Alt+F1` as well as `Ctrl+Alt+F3` behave in the same manner:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 12 hosti tty3

hosti login: root

Login incorrect
hosti login: _
```

I'd like to not need to reinstall `Debian` because I did lots of customisations, which I cannot list all anymore and therefore I'd looking forward to fixing my broken login (or system) way more than reinstalling the system.

**EDIT** Side observation: Trying to take an empty username for login doesn't succeed for the first attempt on the screen, but for the other ones. I also can only take four attempts "once"; the screen "clears" after the fifth attempt.

"Four attempts":

```
Debian GNU/Linux 12 hosti tty3

hosti login: number1

Login incorrect
hosti login: number2

Login incorrect
hosti login: number3

Login incorrect
hosti login: number4

Login incorrect
hosti login: numberFIVEwhichIStheLASToneSEENonTHEscreenAFTERthisONEtheSCREENseemsTOclearORrefreshAUTOMATICALLYafterEXAMININGtheATTEMPTtoLOGin_
```

Comment: are you saying that sometimes the error is "login incorrect" and sometimes the error is "no space left on the device" - but you see there's "some megabytes" free, so you just ignored this error - and what does `I also can only take four attempts "once"` mean? how does one do four attempts once? attempts at what? To be honest, I'd have updated 10->11 and then 11->12 .... you did backup your system before the upgrade, as recommended in every sane guide for upgrading major release

Comment: There is free disk space. Generally, a possible reason why a user cannot log into his system is because there's no space left on the device, which isn't the case on mine.
I did do a backup for the $HOME, but nothing of the rest.

Comment: OK, but `login incorrect` suggests you've typed in the wrong password

Comment: The thing is that I don't get to this point… I'm not prompted for a(ny) password.

Comment: oh, so it doesn't even prompt for password! I missed that point.

Comment: Is it of interest that the kernel of the old system version boots (4.19.0) instead of the one of `Debian 12` (6.1.0)? (Only the kernels already installed before the update are listed in the `GRUB` boot menu.)

Comment: Could I also boot into a live system and install the kernel after `chroot`ing? What are the drawbacks, what the risks of this approach?

Comment: It certainly seems like the upgrade process did not complete successfully. Have you tried selecting "Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux" in the GRUB boot menu, and then picking one of the `(recovery mode)` boot options? If that allows you to get into the system in command line mode, you should re-run `apt full-upgrade` to see if it reports things that still need to be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I have your identical same problem. I was at least able to access a terminal by adding `-rw init=/bin/bash` to the end of the line starting with “Linux“ on the Grub editing screen. Maybe from this point it is possible to do something.